# How to put a Uint value as parameter to a XAML control?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, initialization, xamarin.forms

I search on the web without find a simple and clean way to realize what I want to do.

I have a control `StackOverFlowObject` in XAML which have a `Uint Questions` property.

If I'm doing the following:

```
<local:StackOverFlowObject Questions="23">
```

It will not work because of the C# will read the value as an `int`.

**So how can I set my Uint32 property if C# read the value as an Int32?**

Answer (score 0):

That should work as-is, but I trust you when you say it doesn't. It's even [documented](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/2d57857/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml/TypeConversionExtensions.cs#L133) as not working. (I'm the only one to blame for laziness here, I'll work at fixing it).

There are 2 ways to get this working (actually, 3, the third one being waiting for this to be fixed)

- Attribute your `Questions` property with a `[TypeConverter]` and implement a `string` to `UInt32` conversion.
- change your property type to Uint.

I was about to suggest using a Xaml2009 Language Primitive like this `<x:UInt32>42</x:UInt32>`, [but there's no primitive defined for UInt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792002(v=vs.110).aspx), so THAT WILL NOT WORK EITHER.

As none of the built-in works easily, I'm about to give you the full implementation for the `TypeConverter` option.

### Decorate your property with a `TypeConverter`

```cs
public class StackOverFlowObject
{
    ...

    [TypeConverter(typeof(UIntTypeConverter))]
    public uint Questions {
        get {}  //This can be a normal property or an accessor for a bindable one
        set {}
    }

    ...
}
```

### Declare your TypeConverter

You can derive from abstract `Xamarin.Forms.TypeConverter` so part of the boilerplate is already written for you. Also, this allow some shortcuts while using XamlC.

```cs
public class UIntTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromInvariantString(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            return null;
        return Uint32.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```